# Pass array created in Javascript function to PHP script with second function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have created an array in a Javascript function. Now I want to pass this array to a php-script when I press a button on the html-page. I've tried to pass it calling the following function:

```
function transferarray(param){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'selection.php',
    data:{param:param}
});
```

HTML-Link:

```
<a href='selection.php' id="counter" onclick="transferarray(arr)"></a>
```

(arr: name of the array)

> That does not work though (Notice: Undefined index: param in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DataDict\selection.php on line 17).

Is the array arr even accessible like that? How could I make it accessible?

Please see my code below where the array is created:

```
var n = 0;
var arr = new Array();
function selectionarray(fish){
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var table = document.getElementById("variables");

    fish2=parseInt(fish)+1;
    var row = table.rows[parseInt(fish2)];

    squid = n*(parseInt(fish2));

    for(c=0; c<=squid;c++){
        if(typeof arr[c]==='undefined'){
            arr[c] = new Array();
        }
    }

    checkid='check'+fish;
    if (document.getElementById(checkid).checked){
        for(var j=0, col;col=row.cells[j];j++){
            arr[squid][j] = col.innerText;
        }
        n = n+1;
        counter.innerHTML = "selected Items: " + n;
    }else{  
        n = n-1;
        squid = n*(parseInt(fish2));
        delete arr[squid];
        counter.innerHTML = "selected Items: " + n;
    }
};
```

Javascript creates the array from a table where the checkboxes are dynamically created by another function, that's why I had to use the variable to check for element id.

Comment: and how do you access that param in php?

Comment: If you post a php error you should at the very least also post the relevant php code.

Comment: show code of `selection.php` file

Comment: Please show the relevant PHP code. I'd probably pass a JSON string to `selection.php` and then `json_decode()` to convert it back to an array in your PHP function.

Comment: Hi,I just try to call it via $myArray = $_REQUEST['param'];

Comment: use something other than a hyperlink for this (a button can be made to look like a hyperlink, for instance, and almost any element can be made clickable). What is almost certainly happening is that the hyperlink is doing what hyperlinks do by default, and navigating to selection.php as a full-page GET request, so the output you're seeing is the result of visiting selection.php like that, rather than the ajax call (which, if it ever got started, was cancelled as soon as you navigated away from the original page). Hence it cannot read the param because it doesn't get passed in via this request.

Comment: Or, use a hyperlink but use a jquery unobtrusive event handler with `event.preventDefault()` to handle the click event. This will stop the normal behaviour of the hyperlink and allow the ajax call to proceed. See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/. There's also no need to put `selection.php` into the `href` of your hyperlink, if you actually don't want it to navigate anywhere in the normal way.

Comment: selection.php is a regular html-page that I do want to navigate to and then output the array to a table on that page via php. Actually I just wanted to make sure if one could pass an array created by a JS-function to a php-page by calling it as an argument with another JS-function using ajax to send it. Or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: It seems like 'transferarray()' doesn't recognize 'arr' as a valid argument. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody's interest, I didn't manage to pass the array via ajax to the 'selection.php' page while simultanously redirecting to that page with the link.

I'm using the link now to create a child html-site and pass the array directly to a Javascript on that site:

```
function transferarray(param){  
   var Openwindow = null;
   Openwindow = window.open('selection.html','jav','width=800,height=900,resizable=yes');
   Openwindow.dataFromParent = param;
```

and then calling the array in the child window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataFromParent;    
function init() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('selectiontable');
    elem.innerHTML="";
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<thead><tr><th>Modul</th><th>Name</th><th>Variablename</th><th>Type</th><th>Code</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
    for (var x = 0; x < dataFromParent.length; x++) {
        elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr><td>' + dataFromParent[x][0] + '</td><td>' + dataFromParent[x][1] + '</td><td>' + dataFromParent[x][2] + '</td><td>' + dataFromParent[x][3] + '</td><td>' + dataFromParent[x][4] + '</td></tr>');
    }
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','</tbody>');
}
window.onload = init;
```

I'm using 'window.onload = init' to execute the function because for some reason I'm not able to call it from the parent window via

> 'Openwindow.init();'

Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

Serialize you array with `JSON.stringify()` and post the data

```
function transferarray(param) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selection.php",
    data: {param: JSON.stringify(param)}
    contentType: "application/json",
});
```

use `json_decode` to convert your data to a set of php nested arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still get the same error message though. I stringified the array and posted the data and tried calling it with '$myArray = json_decode($_POST['param']);' in the 'selection.php' page.